# Create related records to contacts/person accounts in lightning experience

Tags: lightning, person-accounts

I have a custom object (call it `Tag__c`). The object has a lookup to the standard `Contact` object (lookup field name: `Contact__c`).

In Lightning Experience I do have the related list Tags on my contact page layout. It displays all tags assigned to a particular contact. The default "New" button within the related lists opens a new dialog windows and lets me add more tags to a contact. It pre-selects the contact I opened the dialog from (by adding its ID 0030000...abc). When I save the dialog, a new tag is added to the contact.

Additionally, the org does have person accounts enabled. On the person account page layout I added the `Tags` related list as well. It displays all the tags that were added to a person account (just like for a contact). So far that's all well and good.

My problem however: When I click the `New` button on the related list within a person account the dialog opens and the current person account record is pre-selected (as desired). Unfortunately Salesforce pre-fills the field with the **Account**-ID of the person account, not the **Contact**-ID (a person account does have both). Since the original lookup was to the `Contact` object, Salesforce throws an error when I try to save the new Tag__c record (*Contact: id value of incorrect type: 0010Y00000abcdef*).

This only happens in Lightning Experience. In Classic everything works fine.
Did anyone come across this problem and solve it? I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere even though this scenario does not seem to be that far fetched...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, for anyone how also experiences this issue: It's an SF bug, see https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CnbQAE